Could someone please simply explain what exchange interaction/Pauli repulsion is and its relation to ferromagnetism?
I consider myself an enthusiast in learning about quantum physics and recently I have been looking at why iron (and cobalt and nickel) is ferromagnetic (I know it is due to the unpaired electrons) and was confused why other half-filled D shell elements like Chromium weren't magnetic either. I went down a pretty big rabbit hole and stumbled upon this concept of exchange interactions: I know the basics of the Pauli exclusion principle and sort of understand wave-function symmetry, but am struggling to understand exactly how it works and why it causes ferromagnetism.
Please try to avoid using complex maths/very long equations (I have a calculus level of maths/senior high school).
